# ios9 - Swift 2.1 - SFSafariViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I'm looking to use the SFSafariViewController and have it automatically load a website when the app is opened. Is this possible?

What I have so far (brand new single ios app):

```
// ViewController.swift
let urlString = "https://stackoverflow.com"

@IBAction func launchSFSafariViewController(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
        let vc = SFSafariViewController(URL: url, entersReaderIfAvailable: true)
        vc.delegate = self

        presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

How do I connect the action to the main view controller via the storyboard? All the articles I see only discuss connecting a button to an action.

Comment: How do you connect _what_ "action"? If you want present on launch, detect that you have launched and present. No "action" is involved.

Comment: Ahhh ok that makes sense. Do I drop the code snippet into `viewDidLoad`, not sure where it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `viewDidAppear` to perform the presentation. (You will need to use a Bool flag, though, to make sure this doesn't happen when you dismiss the presented view controller and `viewDidAppear` is called again!)

Comment: Aight, any chance for a code snippet? If not my google-fu is strong.

Comment: If you don't like my answer, don't accept it. Your question is trivial. I have no intention of writing the code for you.

Comment: Not looking for handouts just figured it would be easy to copy and paste the signature of the `viewDidAppear` function as it is not included in default single app projects. Thanks for pointing me in right direction tho.

Comment: `override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) { super.viewDidAppear(animated) }`